# Cannot enable job in Oracle Standard Edition using DBMS_SCHEDULER

Tags: oracle

We're using 11.2 Oracle Standard Edition and cannot enable a job using DBMS_SCHEDULER. Have we struck a bug?

```
$ sqlplus "/as sysdba"
...
SQL> !cat should.work.sql
begin
     dbms_scheduler.create_job(
            job_name   => 'TEST_JOB',
            job_type   => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
            job_action => 'BEGIN NULL; END;',
            start_date => systimestamp,
            enabled    => false);
  end;
/

select job_name from dba_scheduler_jobs where job_name = 'TEST_JOB';

exec DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable('TEST_JOB');

select job_name from dba_scheduler_jobs where job_name = 'TEST_JOB';

!sleep 2

select job_name from dba_scheduler_jobs where job_name = 'TEST_JOB';

SQL> @should.work.sql

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

JOB_NAME
------------------------------
TEST_JOB

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

JOB_NAME
------------------------------
TEST_JOB

no rows selected

SQL> show errors
No errors.
```

I've created an SR, but there's no Metalink articles, so maybe there's an error on my part. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yep. There was a problem in the syntax. This is the answer from Oracle:

> The job was created to run only one time. Also if you don't specify
>   the attribute "auto_drop" to false the job is dropped after the
>   execution. The default value of auto_drop is true if the attribute is
>   not specified in create job statement.

Simply add "auto_drop => false" to make the job persistent. Hope this helps anyone else running into this problem.